# protecting non .aspx pages with Asp.net Membership provider

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I'm currently using the asp.net membership provider (with logins stored in db) to protect certain pages of my site.  However, I also have non .aspx resources I wish to protect - word docs, excel spreadsheets, pdfs, etc.  Is this even possible? If so how would I go about doing this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are running **IIS 7** under the **integrated pipeline** (the default setup), all requests go through IIS. This means you have to do nothing other than setup your web.config. You'll need to do one little thing though, put the following attribute on the `modules` node under `system.webServer`:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

This ensures that the forms authentication modules run for your static content.